# how to convert IP address into http for urllib

Tags: python, url, networking, download, packet

I'm looking to embark on my own personal project of creating an application which i can save doc/texts/image from the site my browser is at. I have done a lot of research to conclude that either of the two ways is possible for now: using cookies or packet sniffers to identify the IP address(the packet sniffer method being more relevent at the moment).

I would like to automate the application so I would not have to copy and paste the url on my browser and paste it into the script using urllib.

Are there any suggestions that experienced network programmers can provide with regards to the process or modules or libraries I need?

thanks so much
jonathan

Comment: You can use `urllib`, `BeautifulSoup`, `requests` etc. python library to make an app to download images etc as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download all images, docs, and text while you're actively browsing (which is probably a bad idea considering the sheer amount of bandwidth) then you'll want something more than urllib2. I assume you don't want to have to keep copying and pasting all the urls into a script to download everything, if that is not the case a simple urllib2 and beautifulsoup filter would do you wonders.

However if what I assume is correct then you are probably going to want to investigate selenium. From there you can launch a selenium window (defaults to Firefox) and then do your browsing normally. The best option from there is to continually poll the current url and if it is different identify all of the elements you want to download and then use urllib2 to download them. Since I don't know what you want to download I can't really help you on that part. However here is what something like that would look like in selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# Startup the web-browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
current_url = browser.current_url

while True:
    try:
        # If we have a url, identify and download your items
        if browser.current_url != current_url:
            # Download the stuff here
            current_url = browser.current_url
    # Triggered once you close the web-browser
    except:
        break
    # Sleep for half a second to avoid demolishing your machine from constant polling
    sleep(0.5)
```

Once again I advise against doing this, as constantly downloading images, text, and documents would take up a huge amount of space.

Comment: hi thanks for the introduction to selenium! its such a interesting package and i'm so pip up now. Just include a complete sample app/proj where i can choose the page to save from any browser, i.e instapaper